# How to deploy custom JavaScript rules in Sonarqube?

Tags: sonarqube

I recently happened to work on Sonarqube version 5.3. I installed it and the Sonar server is running fine, I even analysed some code and installed some plugins, but now I want to define some custom rules in JavaScript. I downloaded the sample code from Sonarqube website for custom rule in JS.

The downloaded folder has one pom.xml and src folder. I don't know how to deploy this custom rule, somewhere I read that I need to create `.jar` file and place it in "extension/plugins" folder. I am stuck here: I don't know how to generate `.jar` file.

Answer (score 1):

You've downloaded the source code, which is a Maven Project, now you should build the plugin with [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/run-maven/) (`mvn`).

See SonarQube documentation on [Building Plugins](http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/DEV/Build+plugin).

Answer (score 0):

When you download the "javascript custom rule" project from https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-examples/tree/master/plugins/javascript-custom-rules

You can see that it's a Maven project as it has pom.xml

Now you have 2 option to create .jar out of this project.

Option#1: Open this project in Eclipse and do "Run==> maven Clean" and then "Run==> maven install"
It will generate a .jar for you which you can see in Eclipse console.

Option#2: Open Linux terminal or windows cmd, ensure that you  have maven installed. Go to the project path where pom.xml is there and invoke command: "mvn clean install"
It will generate a .jar for you which you can see in console.

Thanks !